# Java's Process.exec, is there a better way to handle it?

Tags: java, process, execution

Easy question for the java experts out there:

Reading [using Process.exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469751/using-process-exec) and http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4 it seems that the only way I can run a process from a java application, get its output (and error stream) and avoid my application from blocking forever, is to create two threads that will consume the stdout and stderr.

Maybe I have been spoiled by .net and python, but this seems like an enormous overkill to running a process. Any other, simpler way to do it?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865362

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really no.  I would recommend [Apache's Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) library which deals with most of the nasty traps with using the Process API.  I use it in production, no issues found.

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what I was looking for, something to take care of the ugly parts for me. Thanks.